# Converting from single channel 12-bit little endian raw binary data

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a raw binary image file where every pixel consists of 12 bit data (gray-scale). For example, the first four pixels in the raw file:

```
0x0  0xC0
0x1  0x05
0x2  0x5C
0x3  0xC0
0x4  0x05
0x5  0x5C
```

This corresponds to 4 pixel values with the value 0x5C0 (little endian).

Unfortunately, using the following command:

```
convert -size 384x184 -depth 12 gray:frame_0.raw out.tiff
```

interprets the pixel values incorrectly (big endian), resulting in the pixel values `0xC00 0x55C 0xC00 0x55C`.

I tried the options `-endian LSB` and `-endian MSB`, but unfortunately they only change the output byte order, not the input byte order.

How do I get convert to open the raw image as 12-bit little endian data?

Comment: I may be  wrong, but I don't believe ImageMagick can deal with 12-bit data like that. I fear you may need to write a little `C` program to extract and pad the data yourself - I did something similar here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/32047138/2836621

Comment: Can you include a link to an example `.raw` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick try at this, but I have no test data but it should be fairly close and easy to detect errors with your images:

```
// pad12to16.c
// Mark Setchell
// Pad 12-bit data to 16-bit
//
// Compile with:
// gcc pad12to16.c -o pad12to16
//
// Run with:
// ./pad12to16 < 12-bit.dat > 16-bit.dat

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define BYTESPERREAD    6
#define PIXPERWRITE     4

int main(){
    unsigned char  buf[BYTESPERREAD];
    unsigned short pixel[PIXPERWRITE];

    // Read 6 bytes at a time and decode to 4 off 16-bit pixels
    while(read(0,buf,BYTESPERREAD)==BYTESPERREAD){
       pixel[0] = buf[0] | ((buf[1] & 0xf) << 8);
       pixel[1] = (buf[2] << 4) | ((buf[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
       pixel[2] = buf[3] | ((buf[2] & 0xf) << 8);
       pixel[3] = (buf[5] << 4) | ((buf[4] & 0xf0) >> 4);
       write(1,pixel,PIXPERWRITE*2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So you would run this (I think):

```
./pad12to16 < 12-bit.dat | convert -size 384x184 -depth 16 gray:- result.tif
```

Answer (score 1):

Mark's answer is correct, as you'll need to involve some external tool to sort-out the data stream. Usually there's some sort of padding when working with 12-bit depth. In the example blob provided, we see that the each pair of pixels share a common byte. The task of splitting the shared byte, and shifting *what-to-where* is fairly easy. This answer compliments Mark's answer, and argues that [ImageMagick's C-API](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php) might as well be used.

```c
// my12bit_convert.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <magick/MagickCore.h>
#include <wand/MagickWand.h>

static ExceptionType serverty;

#define LEADING_HALF(x) ((x >> 4) & 0xF)
#define FOLLOWING_HALF(x) (x & 0xF)
#define TO_DOUBLE(x) ((double)x / (double)0xFFF);
#define IS_OK(x,y) if(x == MagickFalse) { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", MagickGetException(y, &serverty)); }


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // Prototype vars
    int
        i,
        tmp_pixels[2];
    double * pixel_buffer;
    size_t
        w = 0,
        h =0,
        total = 0,
        iterator = 0;
    ssize_t
        x = 0,
        y = 0;
    const char
        * path = NULL,
        * output = NULL;
    unsigned char read_pixel_chunk[3];
    FILE * fh;

    MagickWand * wand;
    PixelWand * pwand;
    MagickBooleanType ok;

    // Iterate over arguments and collect size, input, & output.
    for ( i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) {
        if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
            if (LocaleCompare("size", &argv[i][1]) == 0) {
                i++;
                if (i == argc) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Missing `WxH' argument for `-size'.");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                GetGeometry(argv[i], &x, &y, &w, &h);
            }
        } else if (path == NULL){
            path = argv[i];
        } else {
            output = argv[i];
        }
    }

    // Validate to some degree
    if ( path == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Missing input path\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ( output == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Missing output path\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    total = w * h;
    if (total == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to determine size of %s. (use `-size WxH')\n", path);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Allocated memory and start the party!
    pixel_buffer = malloc(sizeof(double) * total);
    MagickWandGenesis();

    // Read input file, and sort 12-bit pixels.
    fh = fopen(path, "rb");
    if (fh == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read `%s'\n", path);
        return 1;
    }
    while(!feof(fh))  {
        total = fread(read_pixel_chunk, 3, 1, fh);
        if (total) {
            // 0xC0 0x05
            //  ^------'   ==> 0x05C0
            tmp_pixels[0] = FOLLOWING_HALF(read_pixel_chunk[1]) << 8 | read_pixel_chunk[0];
            // 0x05 0x5C
            //   '------^  ==> 0x05C0
            tmp_pixels[1] = read_pixel_chunk[2] << 4 | LEADING_HALF(read_pixel_chunk[1]);
            // 0x5C0 / 0xFFF ==> 0.359463
            pixel_buffer[iterator++] = TO_DOUBLE(tmp_pixels[0]);
            pixel_buffer[iterator++] = TO_DOUBLE(tmp_pixels[1]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fh);

    // Create image
    wand = NewMagickWand();
    pwand = NewPixelWand();
    ok = PixelSetColor(pwand, "white");
    IS_OK(ok, wand);
    // Create new Image
    ok = MagickNewImage(wand, w, h, pwand);
    IS_OK(ok, wand);
    // Import pixels as gray, or intensity, values.
    ok = MagickImportImagePixels(wand, x, y, w, h, "I", DoublePixel, pixel_buffer);
    IS_OK(ok, wand);
    // Save ouput
    ok = MagickWriteImage(wand, output);
    IS_OK(ok, wand);

    // Clean house
    DestroyPixelWand(pwand);
    DestroyMagickWand(wand);
    MagickWandTerminus();
    if (pixel_buffer) {
        free(pixel_buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which can be compiled with

```
LLVM_CFLAGS=`MagickWand-config --cflags`
LLVM_LDFLAGS=`MagickWand-config --ldflags`
clang $LLVM_CFLAGS $LLVM_LDFLAGS -o my12bit_convert my12bit_convert.c
```

And usage

```
./my12bit_convert -size 384x184 frame_0.raw out.tiff
```

Comment: You have excelled yourself! :-)